# How secure are RTMP live streaming services?

Tags: security, youtube, rtmp, live-streaming, twitch

Streaming services such as Twitch or Youtube allow you to stream videos using the RTMP protocol, using an url and a "stream key/name".

Usually the stream url is in this form:

```
 rtmp://rtmp.example.com/live
```

And the stream key

```
123456789abcdefghij
```

but in the end, the url used by streaming softwares is actually :

```
 rtmp://rtmp.example.com/live/123456789abcdefghij
```

Is it only security though obscurity ? The streamkey should be very easy to get trough network sniffing.

Is there a security layer I'm not aware of ?

Comment: You are not missing anything.  The stream key can be easily sniffed off the wire. The “security” comes from the users a ability to change the key anytime.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a security layer I'm not aware of ?

Yes, but it doesn't have a ton of use.  RTMPS is RTMP over TLS.  Facebook Live supports it.  I don't think Twitch does.  I thought YouTube did, but I cannot find a reference to it at the moment.

Without this, you're absolutely correct in that the connection can be sniffed.  As @szatmary says though, these keys are generally one-time-use keys making this not really an issue.

Comment: On a side note, I find it hilarious that a company (Google) requires me to use HTTPS on my local dev VM for things like media device access, but won't even implement the basics of security (RTMPS) on their live ingest.